# The identity connected component of centralizers of unipotent orbits

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, automorphic-forms, nilpotent-orbits

This is, in a way, a follow up question to [Unipotent orbits and intersection with Levi and pseudo-Levi subgroups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415890/unipotent-orbits-and-intersection-with-levi-and-pseudo-levi-subgroups#415890).

I was reading "[A generalisation of the Bala–Carter theorem for nilpotent orbits](https://doi.org/10.1155/S107379289800035X)" by Eric Sommers and was considering the orbit $D_4(a_1)$ in $E_6^\text{ad}$ and there is an issue that I wasn't able to resolve regarding the semi-simple part of the centralizer of this orbit.

According to Sommers, this orbit intersects the principal orbit of the pseudo-Levi subgroup $A_2^3$ and the pair $(A_2^3,3A_2)$ (of pseudo-Levi subgroup and a nilpotent elment of $\mathfrak{e}_6$ that is distinguished in $\mathfrak{l}=\operatorname{Lie}(A_2^3$) corresponds (in the generalized Bala–Carter correspondence described there) to $(N,C)$, where $C$ is the conjugacy class in the component group $A(N)=S_3$ consisting of elements of order $3$: $C=\{(123), (132)\}$.

Now, if I am not mistaken, this pseudo-Levi $L$ of type $A_2^3$ can be realized in $E_6^\text{ad}$ as $\left( \operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{C}) \right)^3 / \mu_3^2$ and its center is $\mu_3$.
Being the principal orbit of $L$, the centralizer of the orbit in $L$ is the center of $L$ (generated by the elements of $C$). The subgroup $L$ has rank $6$ and so its centralizer should have rank $0$.

On the other side, in the table in Carter's book, it says that the semi-simple part of the centralizer of this orbit has type $T_2$ with component group $S_3$.

My question is (assuming my analysis of Sommers' map is correct), how do these two descriptions of the centralizer work together? Where am I missing the rank $2$ torus in the pseudo-Levi description of the orbit?

Comment: How does $\mu_3^2$ sit inside $\operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb C)^3$?  What does "type $T_2$" mean?

Comment: Type $T_2$ in Carter's notations mean a rank 2 torus.

As for how $\mu_3^2$ sits inside $SL_2(\mathbb(C))^3$: To begin with, $SL_2(\mathbb(C))^3$ contains three "interesting" copies of $\mu_3$ - the centers of each of the copies of $SL_2(\mathbb(C))$. We want to identify them, so maybe a better way to phrase the structure of $L$ is:

$L= SL_2(\mathbb(C))\times_{\mu_3} SL_2(\mathbb(C)) \times_{\mu_3} SL_2(\mathbb(C))$

and we take
$\mu_3^2 = \left\{ (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathcal{Z}(SL_2(\mathbb(C)))^3 \vert z_1=z_2=z_3   \right\}$.

Comment: Sorry, that was of course a typo, I meant to write
$\mu_3^2=\left\{ (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathcal{Z}(SL_2(\mathbb(C)))^3 \vert z_1\cdot z_2 \cdot z_3 = 1 \right\}$.
Also, it should be noted that a direct calculation shows that $\mathcal{Z}(L)=\mu_3$ and hence, abstractly this should be the description of $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decompose the $E_6$ Lie algebra over the $3A_2$ subgroup $L$ then, in addition to the adjoint representation, there are two irreducible summands: with the right identifications these are isomorphic to $V^{\otimes 3}$ and its dual ($V$ the natural representation for ${\rm SL} _3$). So, to describe the centraliser of $N$ this way you have to also consider the (${\rm ad} \, N$) -fixed points in these two subspaces. By inspecting weights, we see that $V^{\otimes 3}$, decomposed over the (diagonally embedded) principal ${\mathfrak sl}_2$, equals
$$V(6)\oplus V(4)^2\oplus V(2)^3\oplus V(0).$$
In particular, the centraliser of $N$ in each subspace is 7-dimensional, and the centraliser for the principal ${\mathfrak{sl}}_2$ is one-dimensional. This gives that the reductive part of the centraliser in the whole Lie algebra is 2-dimensional, so must be the Lie algebra of a torus.